# Ansible error: Unable to add user to already existing group

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, ansible

I am unable to add user to an already existing group. After executing, on verifying from `/etc/groups` I can see that user is not added. I am new to Ansible. Could anyone help?

This is the script I am using:

```
 hosts: host1
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
  - name: Creating user arun with shell login
    user:
     name: arun
     password: redhat
     shell: /bin/bash
  - name: creating group
     group:
     name: arungrp
     state: present
  - name: adding test user to group
     user:
      name: test
      group: arungrp
      append: yes
```

Comment: Is there any error written to a log?

Comment: Actually error is not there.every task run perfectly.But user is not added to the group.

Answer (score 1):

Append is a modifier for group**s**, not group.

Do you want arungrp as the secondary group?

```
- name: creating group
     group:
     name: arungrp
     state: present
 - name: Creating user arun with shell login
     user:
      name: test
      password: redhat
      shell: /bin/bash
      groups: arungrp
      append: yes
```

If you want it as a primary group:

```
- name: creating group
     group:
     name: arungrp
     state: present
- name: Creating user arun with shell login
    user:
     name: arun
     password: redhat
     shell: /bin/bash
     group: arungrp
```